# Why is an extra await required in my vue.js unit test when more than one call is made to my firebase auth mock?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, firebase-authentication, jestjs, vue-test-utils

I have a `vue.js` app that uses firebase authentication. When unit-testing my `Login.vue` component, I mock firebase auth by mocking the config file I use to initialize firebase (named `firebase.config`). I should note that `firebase.auth()` is being exported from my config file as `auth`, hence the use of `fb.auth` and not `fb.auth()` in my code.

One of my tests checks that if the user is authenticated but not `emailVerified`, an email dialog is displayed. The dialog is not part of the test, but whether the `dialogEmail` data property is being set to `true` is what the test is asserting.

As part of the sign-in process, I set my firebase authentication state persistence to 'session'. Though this combination is not an issue for my app, it's giving me an issue in my test.

From `Login.vue` (abbreviated component code):

```js
<template>
  <v-btn @click="signInUser(email, password)">
    Sign in
  <v/btn>
</template>

<script>
import * as fb from '@/firebase.config';

export default {
  data () {
    return {
      email: '',
      password: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async signInUser (email, password) {
      try {
        await fb.auth.setPersistence('session');
        const { user } = await fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

        if (user.emailVerified) {
          this.$router.push('/home');
        } else {
          this.dialogEmail = true;
        }
      } catch (err) {
        // ...error handling
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

From `login.spec.js`:

```js
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
import { mount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils';
import Login from '@/views/Login';

jest.mock('@/firebase.config', () => ({
  auth: {
    setPersistence: () => Promise.resolve(),
    signInWithEmailAndPassword: () => Promise.resolve({ user: { emailVerified: false } }),
  },
}));

const localVue = createLocalVue();
const $router = { push: jest.fn() };

describe('login.vue', () => {
  let vuetify;

  beforeEach(() => {
    vuetify = new Vuetify();
  });

  const mountFunction = () => mount(Login, {
    localVue,
    vuetify,
    mocks: { $router },
  });

  it('shows dialog if user email not verified on sign in', async () => {
    expect.assertions(1);
    const wrapper = mountFunction();
    const signInButton = wrapper.find('[data-test="signIn"]');
    await wrapper.setData({ email: 'foo@bar.org', password: 'FooBarBaz' });
    await signInButton.trigger('click');
    expect(wrapper.vm.dialogEmail).toBe(true);
  });
});
```

My app works fine. My test does not. It fails with an output of:

```sh
expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality    

    Expected: true
    Received: false
```

However, my test WILL pass on one of two conditions:

1. I remove either of my `await` code snippets in my `signInUser()` method. This results in only one call to my mock function, which somehow helps.
2. I add a short wait to my test just before my assertion, like this (abbreviated test code):

```js
  await signInButton.trigger('click');
  await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 0)); // my added code
  expect(wrapper.vm.dialogEmail).toBe(true);
```

I'm elated that option #2 works, so that's what I'm doing. The question I have, however, is why does this extra timeout work, and why is it required? I'd like to understand what's happening, so I'm asking about it here.

Answer (score 1):

In sign in user function, you are waiting for 2 promises to be resolved:

```
await fb.auth.setPersistence('session');
const { user } = await fb.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
```

Inside test you added `await signInButton.trigger('click');` but this will just trigger the function call, but not waiting for until its complete.

So you must add mock `promise` resolve inside test after you called the signin function.

`setTimeout` with 0 will add the `promise` at the end of the tasks queue so the test will be delayed there until the end of the function.

Comment: How would I do what you're suggesting?  Also, are you saying my `setTimeout` solution is not a good way to resolve the issue?

Comment: If, perchance, there were 3 or more promises being waited for instead of 2, does the `setTimeout` call suffice to handle all of them, or is another solution required? I'm thinking the latter.

Comment: Yes, it will handle that case as well since your `expect` will be called after all promises are resolved. It will work even though you add 100 requests!